Could a gas giant still be low on the horizon from the equator of a tidally locked moon?
So I am working on a small animated series; obviously a visual medium.
It is set on an Earth-like tidally locked moon of a ringed gas giant, more specifically, in a city built at the base of a space elevator.
The dilemma here:
Visually, I want the gas giant to appear fairly low on the horizon, and I want the rings to be fairly visible, so you get a cool background and interesting silhouettes.
Basically, a horizon sort of like this: https://media.sciencephoto.com/image/c0180224/800wm/C0180224-Saturn_from_Titan,_artwork.jpg
However, realistically, the gas giant could only be that low on the horizon near the poles of the moon, and if the moon had a highly inclined orbit; at the equator the gas giant would appear straight overhead with the rings a thin line across it, while a space elevator can only be built on the equator and tidally locked moons have no inclination.
So these two aspects of the setting are at directly opposed.
Is there some combination of rare circumstances such as the moon having been a captured planet, or the moon having impacted with another moon in the past, that would still give its orbit the inclination and tilt needed for the gas giant to appear low on the horizon even at the equator? Or for that matter, can a space elevator be built away from the equator somehow?
Now, ultimately, this is something I am willing to compromise on realism for rule of cool, but since I have been trying to keep the science relatively accurate in every other aspect, I figured I would at least try to come up with a plausible in-universe explanation.

Of course the tether of a space elevator can be anchored away from the Equator. Why wouldn't it? It works just like a good old-fashioned amusement park swing ride. Here is a video of such a swing ride in Nuremberg.

The obvious sites for an elevator on a tide-locked moon are the in-pole (to L1) and the out-pole (to L2).  Elsewhere, what force holds it up?  Tide-locked bodies rotate very slowly, so a synchronous orbit is likely to be outside its Hill sphere.  I suppose an elevator could run between a Lagrange point and an arbitrary surface point, in which case near the bottom it may be near horizontal.

By the way, Earth's moon is tide-locked and inclined; its equator is much closer to the ecliptic than its orbit is.

@AlexP The forces acting on an elevator cable that's not straight are considerable.

Note that the term "equator" doesn't have all that much meaning for a tidally locked moon.

If the setting of the story is on a high advanced society: is there a reason they havent rotated the moon by 90 degrees so the rotation of the moon is on the red-line of LDutch sketch.
That way you could have dusk and dawn while being tidellocked and have the elevator on the equator. The equator would be the red line.

Is what you mean: they would spin up the moon in a direction where the red line becomes its equator and one of the poles would be pointing straight at the planet? That would work, twice a month. Unfortunately the direction of the axis of rotation doesn't rotate along when the moon orbits around the planet, so the moon's axis of rotation will only point to the planet twice a month. Although the planet would still be on the horizon twice per rotation, when the planet rises and sets. The same would be true for a spin-up in any orientation.

This famous picture shows the planet of a tidally locked moon low on the horizon, exactly as you asked:

for the planet to be close to the horizon the observer needs only to be close to the equivalent of the terminator for the planet-moon pair: along that circumference the planet will always appear low on the horizon.
In the below rough drawing you can see what I mean:

any observer along the red line on the moon would see the gas giant on the horizon.

Ah, so you have the elevator on the equator, but along the terminator line dividing the planet facing side and the "dark" side. So it would always appear near the horizon to either the East or West of you, depending which hemisphere you are on?
lol I'm not sure why that didn't occur to me, I wasn't thinking of this three dimensionally I guess.
Thanks!

I wonder how tides would play with a space elevator in this configuration...

@BMF I would be curious of that as well.
Also, putting it on the terminator line would mean the elevator would either be going ahead of the moon along its orbit, or always trailing behind it, depending.
I would think that having it trail behind the moons orbit would make the elevator safer from being hit by debris since it would have the whole moon between it and the path of motion, but as far as which side would be best for structural stress, or for lowering the delta v needed for spacecraft to launch from or dock to it, I'm not sure.

@TheyMightBeGiantSquids It might be slightly worse than you initially think because, for small captured rocks, the most stable orbits around gas giants are retrograde, which you can see by looking at how most moons of the giants in Sol, except those that formed alongside their parent planets, orbit backwards. So it's possible lots of debris will come in at unusually high velocities on the orbit-facing hemisphere.

An elevator cable must be in tension or it just falls down.  The only way you get tension is by placing sufficient mass sufficiently above synchronous orbit.  But tidally locked moons do not have synchronous orbits because synchronous orbital height is outside their Hill Sphere.  Thus you need to get tension from your primary and that means on a line through the center of both primary and moon.

In the configuration as shown, you could make your moon having an inclination of 90 degrees, pointing with one of the poles towards the gas giant. Have the moon thus tidally locked, but let it rotate around it's equator still. Your elevator then gets slung around the moon. Would this work? Maybe someone could explore this in an answer?

@Marcel That wouldn't be possible: a body that always shows the same face to its primary has to have a small inclination. That's how it always shows the same face, because it's rotating on its axis at the same rate that it's revolving around its primary. It's not necessarily exactly 0 (or 180) - the moon's inclination is around 1.5 degrees, for example - but always pointing the same face means you have to be rotating on an axis close to perpendicular to your orbital plane.

The problem with your setting is the location of the elevator.  Space elevators can be in a location where the orbital rotation lines up with the rotation of the ground, which doesn't work for tidally locked moons, or it can be centered on a lagrange point.  Shown below are the 5 stable orbital lagrange points between a moon and planet.

A stable space elevator could theoretically be built from the L1 or L2 points to the ground, the other points are too far away.  So your space elevators are going to be inline with the planet being orbited, making the view you want impossible.

The Lagrange points are points of equilibrium, not stability.  Equilibrium means that if you are exactly there, you stay there.  Stable equilibrium means that if you drift off a little, you drift back.  (I haven't done the math myself, but as I understand it:)  L4 and L5 are points of stable equilibrium, provided some mass ration restrictions are met - you can put an object there and expect it to stay there long term.  (The restrictions mean this is actually called "metastable".)  The other 3 are not stable in all directions, but may be stable in some directions.

You are of course correct, it was perhaps a poor choice of words, but any actual space elevator is not going to be stable either, it will require much monitoring and active orbital manipulation to maintain, but to be even theoretically possible it would be balanced on L1 or L2

Well, it would need to be well beyond that, the normal mis-description of the space elevator.  The normal space elevator you lift or lower to geostationary level, because you can get on/off there.  But the elevator must go further up (away from the moon), and the top is better if you want escape velocity.  For a beyond L1 or L2 based elevator, you can get on/off at L1/L2.  (To get on/off, you must be able to navigate a ship at low relative speed and dock with the elevator.  I.e. there must be an unpowered orbit there.)  I couldn't begin to tell you how the math works out here.

What does "too far away" mean? This is science fiction, and materials considerations are pretty easy to ignore.

How far... all the way around probably.  Simplistically space elevators work by balancing their center of mass in orbit over a planet with one end on the planet, that means the upper end has to be much further than the orbit point, and they work best when they are straight to distribute the forces, imagine pushing a rope sideways. An L4/L5 space elevator would have to extend so far, and be bent by the main planet's gravity, you are effectively building an orbital ring, which is a different class of mega-structure. So not impossible, but not a space elevator.

Straight refers to the lack of bends in the tether, not the angle to the ground, right? I don't see a convincing argument against a tether at an angle that's not 90^o to the ground here. From what I can see on the topic, the research indicates that satellites must be within the Hill Sphere, not tethers. While they share attributes, the tether would be getting force at the ground which makes it a different object.

So I was doing some more looking around and I found a proposal for a space elevator on the moon with two tethers, one at the equator and one near one of the poles.
Obviously scaling this up to a more Earth sized moon would require stronger materials and be more expensive, but would there be any other issues with an elevator design like this?
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/255538079_Lunar_Space_Elevators_for_CisLunar_Transportation

The problem with tethers at angles to the ground is gravity pulls it towards the ground, so your tether which is strong in tension is being pulled sideways, you can balance this with some complicated angular forces, such as a second tether, but again all of these make the incredibly difficult space elevator more complex and unstable.

@Josh King  I have finally Sept. 2, completed an answer to you question discussing two possible situations.

For the space elevator:
Where is the elevator supposed to elevate to? If it is to connect the moon to the gas giant, they need to be mutually tidaly locked. For that scenario the panets rotation axis must be coaxiall with moon orbit axis and parallel to moon's rotation axis. Otherwise the elevator snaps because of the relative movements. See: Randall Munroe's What-if
For the Saturn from Titan artwork:
The rings are formed of the debris orbitting the planet and they may originate from the time of the planet and moons forming. It's easy to expect those all share the same rotation/orbit axis.
I will use L.Dutch's sketch to describe in more detail.

Suppose the moon orbits in the plane of the screen. Then the red line (red circle, actually) are all the points you can see the giant on the horizon. As the moon is "natural" it is in the plane of the belt so the belt is seen as a line. As you travel along the red circle the giant's belt tilts. On the pole (the centre of red line here) the belt is horizontal, on the equator (the black moon outline) the belt is vertical.
If the moon was acqured it doesn't need to share its orbital axis with the giant's rotational one (the elevator is ruled out). In that case the belt would show as ellipsis (in the extreme as a line) on the sketch and as the moon orbits the belt "dances" and you can see horizon as in the provided image.

I wrote an answer, probably on August 19, but I accidentally deleted it before it was finished.
Part One.  A Typical Space Elevator.
A typical space elevator is goes from the equator of a planet to geosynchronous orbit and beyond, and usually has a large space station or captured asteroid in the geosynchronous orbit.
So in your story there should be an artificial satellite or artificially captured asteroid orbiting the moon in question and anchoring the space elevator, with the moon orbiting a giant planet and the giant planet orbiting its star.  And possibly it is a binary star system and the star which the planet orbits a more massive star.  And presumably the star(s) orbit the center of their galaxy.
Scientists have discussed the requirements for worlds to be habitable for life.  And usually the scientists have discussed habitability for liquid water using life in general.  Worlds habitable for humans are thus a smaller subset of worlds habitable for liquid water using life in general.
The only scientific discussion of habitability for humans (and lifeforms with similar requirements is Stephen H. Dole Habitable Planets for Man (1964).
https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf
In the last couple of decades there have been some articles discussing the potential habitability of hypothetical moons in other star systems, exomoons orbiting exoplanets.
Here is a link to an article from 2013 "Exomoon habitability constrained by illumination and tidal heating" by Rene Heller and Rory Barnes.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5323
On page 3 they write:

The longest possible length of a satellite’s day compatible with Hill stability has been shown to be about P∗p/9, P∗p being the
planet’s orbital period about the star (Kipping 2009a)

The bibliography lists the article as:  Kipping, D. M. 2009a, MNRAS, 392, 181.  MNRAS is Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society
https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=en&user=UXY08zEAAAAJ&citation_for_view=UXY08zEAAAAJ:u5HHmVD_uO8C
They are assuming that a satellite will be tidally locked to the planet and thus its rotation period will be the same length as its orbital period around the planet.
So a moon's orbital period around its planet should be no more than 1/9 or 0.111111111 as long as the planet's orbit around its star.
So if the satellite which orbits the moon has a orbital period of 1 time unit, the moon should have an orbital period of at least 9 time units around the planet, and the planet should have an orbital period around the star of at least 81 time units.
But if the moon is tidally locked to the planet, its rotational period will be the same as its orbital period. And thus the period of a satellite of the moon in moon synchronous orbit around the moon will have the same period as the moon's orbit around the planet.
But for orbital stability the satellite around the moon will need to have an orbital period no more than 0.1111111 as long as the moon's orbital period around the planet (and thus rotational period of the moon if it is tidally locked to the planet).
And if the satellite anchoring the space elevator has an orbital period less than the rotational period of the moon the space elevator will wind around the equator of the moon, pulling itself and the satellite down in a terrible disaster, or breaking the space elevator.
So it seems like it would be impossible for your moon to have a space elevator because the anchoring satellite could not have a long term stable orbit around the moon.
But Heller and Barnes offer some hope for you on page
3:

Since the satellite’s rotation period also depends on its orbital
eccentricity around the planet and since the gravitational drag of further moons or a close host star could pump the satellite’s
eccentricity (Cassidy et al. 2009; Porter & Grundy 2011), exomoons might rotate even faster than their orbital period.

And here are the links to the articles which claim that exomoons might rotate faster than their orbital periods.
https://typeset.io/papers/massive-satellites-of-close-in-gas-giant-exoplanets-kdr6kvgq2j
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/258557026_KCTF_Evolution_of_Trans-Neptunian_Binaries
Thus it may be possible for a moon of a gas giant planet to have a rotational period which is shorter than its orbital period around the planet - possibly even less than 0.11111111 of the orbital period.  Thus it might be possible for your moon to have the anchor satellite of the space elevator in a stable orbit and not destroy the space elevator.
If your moon rotates in a fraction of its orbital period around the planet, at any place on the equator of the moon the planet will be visible half the time.  It will appear to rise, reach the zenith, and set, just like the Sun and the Moon appear to from Earth.
Thus the planet and its rings will be invisible about half the time, and high in the sky part of the time, and low on the horizon only around the times of planet rise and planet set.
And if that is not good enough for you, and you want the planet low on the horizon all the time, there is another possibility.
A large regular moon of a giant planet should have its orbit quickly made almost circular and in the plane of the planet's equator by tidal interactions.  The axial tilt of the moon's rotational axis should be pulled by tidal interactions so that the equator of the moon will be in the plane of the moon's orbit around the planet.
This should happen in just a few tens of millions of years.
But the rotational periods and axial tilts of planets are partially or largely determined by large impacts late in the formation of planets.  Such a large impact is believed to cause the large axial tilt of Uranus.
So possibly the planet and the moon formed, and after tens of millions of years the moon orbited in the equatorial plane of the planet and the moon's axial tilt put its  equator in the plane of its orbit around the planet, and the moon was tidally locked  to the planet.  And then a large object falling toward the planet happened to hit the moon which happened to be in the way.  The impact could have greatly speeded up the rotation of the moon and changed the rotational axis of the moon.
Perhaps the new rotational axis of the moon will now be almost in the plane of its orbit.  Which will mean that the moon will "seasons" in it's orbit around the planet.
In one season the moon's north pole will point at the planet and the planet will be low on the horizon as seen from the equator all day and all night.
In the opposite season the moon's south pole will point at the planet and the planet will be low on the horizon as seen from the equator all day and all night.
There will be two other seasons where the planet will rise, come to the zenith, and set, once each rotation of the moon.
And there will be four intermediate seasons between the four seasons previous mentioned, when the configuration will change.
And think that if the moon's axis is titled that way, the planet will be on the horizon constantly for some seasons of the year, and more often than if the moon's equator is in the orbital plane.
Added Sept. 2, 2024:
So hypothetically a habitable moon of a giant planet could rotate much faster than it orbital period, and it could have an axial tilt close to 90 degrees which would make the equator - where the base of a space elevator would be - almost 90 degrees from the direction to the planet, and thus keep the planet low near the horizon part of the time.
So far so good.
But as I said above, the space elevator will have to have a large satellite, possibly a captured asteroid, at the moon synchronous and geostationary orbit to anchor the space elevator.  So whatever the distance of the orbiting satellite, and thus whatever the orbital period of the satellite, the moon will have to rotate at exactly the same period to keep from breaking the space elevator, and to keep the city at the base of the space elevator.
Every planet which orbits a star, and every moon which orbits a planet, has a Hill sphere.  Within the Hill sphere natural and artificial satellites can have stable orbits.
The four major Galilean moons of Jupiter have orbits with semi-major axes of 421,800 Km (Io), 671,100 km (Europa), 1,070,400 km (Ganymede), and 1,882,700 km (Callisto).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Jupiter#List
Saturn's five largest moons orbit with semi-major axes of 294,619 km (Tethys), 377,396 km (Dione), 527,108 km (Rhea), 1,221,870 km (Titan), and 3,560,820 km (Iapetus).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Saturn#List
According to this Hill Sphere Radius calculator:
https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/hill-sphere-radius
If the planet has the mass of Jupiter (317.8 times the mass of Earth) and the moon has the mass of Earth:
A moon at 500,000 kilometers would have a Hill radius of 48,261.62 km.
However, the region of true long term orbital stability around an astronomical object only extends to one third or one half of the Hill radius. In this case that would be 16,087 or 24,130 km.
A moon at 1,000,000 kilometers would have a Hill radius of 96,523 km, and thus a true region of stability out to 32,174.333 or 48,261.5 km.
A moon at 1,500,000 kilometers would have a Hill radius of 144,784.859 km, and thus a true region of stability out to 48,261.6 or 72,392.43 km.
The planet Earth rotates with a period of 23 hours, 56 minutes, and 4 seconds with respect to the stars, or about 0.99935 24-hour days.  A geosynchronous orbit with a semi-major axis of 42,227 km should have an orbital period of 23.99 days.  A Earth geosynchronous orbit has an altitude above the surface of 35,788 km.  42,277 minus 35,788 km leaves 6,439 km as the radius of the Earth, and the equatorial radius of Earth is actually  6,378.137 km.
So if your moon has the mass of Earth and rotates at about the same speed, the geosynchronous and geostationary anchor satellite can have a stable orbit if the Moon orbits at 1east 1,500,000 km from a Jupiter mass planet.  If the planet has a lower mass a stable orbit could be farther from the moon at the same distance from the planet, or the same distance from the moon if the moon is closer to the planet.
Because the Earth rotates, it is not a perfect sphere but an oblate spheroid.  The equatorial radius of 6,378.137 km is about 1.003364139 times the polar radius of 6,356.752 km. If the Earth rotated faster the equator would bulge more and more.
And the faster the Earth rotated, the lower the geostationary orbit would be, and thus the shorter the space elevator would have to be, especially since the equator would bulge upward more. That might significantly reduce the amount of material, and thus the cost, to build the space elevator.
Stephen H. Dole, in Habitable Planets for Man (1964)
https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf
Discusses the relationship between rotation speeds and oblateness on pages 41 to 46.  And he discusses the range of rotation rates consistent with habitability for humans on pages 58 to 60.
Dole considered the upper limit for rotation speed to be where matter at the equator was moving faster than orbital speed and was lost into space, or the planet's shape became too unstable.  De considered a rotation period or two to three hours to be the limit for the fastest rotation, and about 96 hours (four Earth days) to be the limit for slow rotation.
If your moon rotated so fast the rotation period was only 4 hours, That might be safe for humans to inhabit.  A satellite with an orbital semi-major axis at 12,790 kilometers would have an orbital period of 3.999 hours, and one with a semi-major axis of 12,793 km would have an orbital period of 4 hours.
Going back to Heller and Barnes "Exomoon habitability constrained by illumination and tidal heating", on page 3 they first assume that a satellite would be tidally locked to its primary.

The longest possible length of a satellite’s day compatible with Hill stability has been shown to be about P∗p/9, P∗p being the
planet’s orbital period about the star (Kipping 2009a).

That means the moon's orbital period around the planet should be no more than 1/9 or 0.11111 of the planet's orbital period around the star.
And then Heller and Barnes say that the satellite might possibly rotate faster than being tidally locked.

Since the satellite’s rotation period also depends on its orbital
eccentricity around the planet and since the gravitational drag of further moons or a close host star could pump the satellite’s
eccentricity (Cassidy et al. 2009; Porter & Grundy 2011), exomoons might rotate even faster than their orbital period.

I also suggested that a giant impact might have speeded up the rotation of the moon and tilted its axis.
Since the satellite which anchors the moon's space elevator has to be in a moon synchronous and moon stationary orbit, the moon has to rotate much faster than if it was tidally locked to the planet and thus has to have rotation period much less than its orbital period around the planet.
Since the ratio of satellite orbital period to moon orbital period should have the same limits as the ratio of moon orbital period to planetary orbital period, the satellite in geostationary orbit should have an orbital period of 1/9 or 0.11111 of the orbital period of the moon, or less.  And thus the rotational period of the moon must be 1/9 or0.11111 of its orbital period or less.
And I just suggested that the rotation period of the moon should be between 4 Earth hours and 96 Earth hours (0.166666 to 4 Earth days).  And so the orbital period of the moon around the planet should be 36 to 864 Earth hours (1.5 to 36 Earth days) or longer.
The greater the semi-major axis of a moon's orbit is (the farther it orbits from the planet) the longer its orbital period will be.  The less massive a moon's planet is the longer its orbital period will be at the same distance from the planet.
And above I listed the semi-major axes of the orbits of the four large moons of Jupiter and the five largest moons of Saturn.
So here are their orbital periods
1.7627 days (Io), 3.5525 days (Europa), 7.1556 days (Ganymede), 16.690 days Callisto), 1.88780 days (Tethys), 2.73692 days (Dione), 4.51750 days (Rhea), 15.9454 days (Titan), 79.3310 days (Iapetus).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Jupiter#List
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moons_of_Saturn#List
Thus it seems plausible for your moon to have a rotational period and an orbital period enabling a moon stationary satellite of the moon to anchor a space elevator from the moon to space.
Part Two: A Ring of Moons Around the planet.
And here is a suggestion for something rather different from what you asked for.
An astrophysicist named Sean Raymond has a blog called planetplanet.
https://planetplanet.net/about/
Many of his posts are interesting to science fiction readers and writers.
For example, he has a section called Building the Ultimate Solar System where he tries to design scientifically possible star systems with as many potentially habitable planets as possible.
By the time Raymond gets to the post called The Ultimate Engineered Solar System he has to admit that such a star system could never form in nature but would have to be created by a super advanced society whose technology makes them almost like gods.

I can only think of one way our 416-planet system could form. It must have been purposely engineered by a super-intelligent advanced civilization.  I’m calling it the Ultimate Engineered Solar System.

https://planetplanet.net/2017/05/03/the-ultimate-engineered-solar-system/
Raymond mentions a paper from 2010 by Smith and Lissauer discussing the stability of a ring of equally spaced planets around a star.
https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010CeMDA.107..487S/abstract
If ring of planets around a star can be stable, a ring of moons, including Earth-like moons which may be Earth-mass moons, around a giant planet can also be stable.
And if each moon was tidally locked to their planet, each would also be tidally locked to each of the other moons, at least in the sense that a line from the center of one moon to the center of another moon would always pass through the same spots on the surfaces of both moons.
And thus a physical space elevator could stretch along the line from one Earth-like moon to the nearest Earth-like moon.  And thus the space elevator could be used to travel between two Earth-like worlds.
Naturally the cities around the bases of such an elevator would become very large and prosperous if there is any trade between moons.
And of course each city at the base of a space elevator leading to the nearest moon would be at almost 90 degrees from the direction to the planet and its rings, so the planet and the rings would always be low toward the horizon as seen from cities at the bases of the space elevators.
You can have one space elevator linking two of the moons, or more space elevators, up to as many space elevators as is necessary to link each moon to both of its nearest neighbors and form a complete transportation system around the planet.
Of course there would be problems which you might want to solve or just ignore.
Because Earth's moon rotates at a constant rate, a constant number of degrees per day, but has a slightly elliptical orbit nd slightlychanging orbital speed, the number of degrees  it travels along the orbit per day can change slightly.

In lunar astronomy, libration is the cyclic variation in the apparent position of the Moon perceived by Earth-bound observers and caused by changes between the orbital and rotational planes of the moon. It causes an observer to see slightly different hemispheres of the surface at different times. It is similar in both cause and effect to the changes in the Moon's apparent size due to changes in distance. It is caused by three mechanisms detailed below, two of which cause a relatively tiny physical libration via tidal forces exerted by the Earth. Such true librations are known as well for other moons with locked rotation.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libration
So the libration of the Moon, and all moons that are tidally looked to their planets, cause them to wobble slightly with respect to their planets.  Which means that moons in a ring around a planet would also wobble slightly with respect to their nearest neighbor moons.
And because all orbits are at least slightly elliptical, each moon might be at some times slightly closer to the planet and at other times slightly farther from the planet than its nearest neighbors.  Which would put changing stresses on the space elevators.
Which would be bad for the space elevators.
Thus you would have to assume that the space elevators were put into very, very, very, very, very, very close to circular obits by the super advanced beings who built the ring of Earth-like moons to reduce the stress on the space elevators to tolerable limits.
I guess that for the rings to be stable, they would have to be in the plane of the planet's equator, and for the ring of moons to be stable, it would have to be in the plane of the planet's equator.  Thus the rings and the circle of moons would have to orbit in the same plane.
That would mean that the rings would appear as a thin line trough the planet as seen from the point on a moon which was directly pointing toward the center of the planet.
Since the moons would all have (nearly) zero axial tilt their equators would be be in the plane that the moons and the rings orbited in.
Earth has a polar radius of about 6,356.3752 kilometers. If the Earth-like moons have similar polar radii their poles would be about 6,300 to 6,400 km "above" or "below" the plane of the rings and thus give a slightly more full view of the rings.
So possibly the space elevators are attached to the rotational poles of the moon and thus have a slightly better view of the rings.
Possibly the rings could have a much greater "vertical" thickness than the rings of Saturn, thus giving the moons a somewhat thicker and less linear view of the rings.
And possibly the super advanced society which created the circle of co-orbital moons around the planet checks on it from time to time.  And whenever they detect a species of intelligent beings has evolved on one of the moons, they bring a large asteroid (or several) to a position within the Roche limit of the planet so it breaks up into billions of particles which eventually form a ring.
The super advanced society can give the asteroids they send into the Roche limit orbits designed so that their particles and the rings the particles form orbit at an an angle to the equatorial plane of the planet.  And thus the intelligent beings on a moon will have a good slanted view of the rings.
Of course the planet's equatorial bulge will eventually pull the rings into the planet's equatorial plane, but the natives of the moon might have a good view for hundreds of thousands or millions of years.
Or maybe the super advanced society will not wait for intelligent life to naturally evolve on the moons one by one, and thus have to create many separate spectacular ring systems in the different eras of the different intelligent species.  Maybe they will use genetic engineering to create at least one intelligent species on each of the moons simultaneously and create one ring system for all the intelligent beings on all of the moons to enjoy.
How far from the giant planet should the ring of Earth-like moons orbit?
There is a limit to how close the ring of moons can be to the planet and remain habitable.
I have previous mentioned "Exomoon habitability constrained by illumination and tidal heating", Rene Heller and Rory Barnes, 2013.
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1209.5323
This article introduced the concept of a "habitable edge" for giant planets. A moon must orbit outside the "habitable edge" of a giant planet in order to avoid excessive tidal heating and a runaway greenhouse effect.
Heller and Jorge Zuluaga authored "Magnetic shielding of exomoons beyond the habitable edge" 2013.
https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2041-8205/776/2/L33/pdf
In it they discussed the formation of planetary magnetic fields and their extension to enclose some of a planet's moons. A planetary magnetic field could subject a moon orbiting in a radiation belt of the planet to high levels of radiation. And it could sometimes also protect a moon without its own magnetic field from cosmic radiation and the stellar wind.
The abstract says:

Moons at distances between about 5 and 20 planetary radii from a giant planet can be habitable from an illumination and tidal heating point of view...

So it seems that 5 planetary radii would be the habitable edge and 20 planetary radii the outer edge of the magnetic field.
If the planet has the same equatorial radius as Jupiter - 71,492 km - its habitable edge might be at 5 radii or 357,460 km.
If the planet has the same equatorial radius as Jupiter - 71,492 km - its magnetic field might extend out to 20 radii or 1,429,840 km.
It is uncertain whether your Earth-like moons would have to orbit inside the planetary magnetic field or could have their own magnetic fields to protect their atmospheres from charged particles.
In any case, the absolute outer limit for the ring of moons to have stable orbits would be one third to one half of the Hill sphere radius of the planet.
If the planet has 1 Jupiter mass (and you can change the mass), and the star has 1 solar mass (and you can change the mass of the star) and if the planet orbits at 1 AU (and you can change the semi-major axis of the orbit), then the planet would have a Hill sphere radius of 9,702,012.503  kilometers according to this Hill sphere radius calculator.
https://www.vcalc.com/wiki/hill-sphere-radius
Thus your ring of moons should probably have an orbit somewhere between 357,460 km, and either 1,429,840 km or 9,702,012.503 km, assuming a Jupiter mass planet orbiting a Sun mass star at 1 AU.
Going back to Sean Raymond's post:
https://planetplanet.net/2017/05/03/the-ultimate-engineered-solar-system/
He writes:

It turns out there is a stability limit for the number of planets that can be spread along the same orbit. The planets must be evenly spaced and there must be at least 7 on one orbit (not a typo: at least 7!). The limit is simple: the planets sharing the same orbit must be separated by at least 12 Hill radii in distance along the orbit.

And presumably the same goes for moons orbiting a planet orbiting a star.  They must be separated by at least 12 Hill radii along their common orbit.
So now I calculate the Hill radius of an Earth moss moon orbiting a Jupiter mass planet, putting the planet in the place of the star and the moon in the place of the planet.
At a semi-major axis of 357,460 km, the Hill sphere of an Earth mass moon would be 34,502.967 km and 12 times that would 414,035.604 km.  The orbit would have a circumference of 2,245,985.523 km and 5.424 moons could fit along that orbit.  But at least 7 moons would be needed for a stable orbit.
If the orbit has a semi-major axis of 1,000,000 kilometers it will have a circumference of 6,283,180 kilometers.  The moon will have a Hill radius of 96,522.595, and 12 times that will be 1,158,271.14 km, and there will be room for 5.426193 moons in that orbit.
So the number of Hill radii per orbit remains approximately the same no matter which orbit is used.
So now I try making the mass of the planet 10 times Jupiter.  As it happens planets much more massive than Jupiter get denser instead of much larger.  The radius of a 10 Jupiter mass planet at 1 AU from a Sun-like star should be about 20 percent larger, or 85,790.4 km, or smaller.  Thus the habitable edge of that planet should be at about 428,952 km.  An orbit at 428,952 km would have a circumference of 2,695,182.627 km.  And an Earth-mass moon would have a Hill radius of 19,217.83 km.  12 times that would be 230,613.96 km, and there would be room for 11.686 moons in that orbit.
And I expect that all orbits around a 10 Jupiter mass planet would have room for 11.686 Earth mass moons in ring.
The lower mass limit for a human habitable world may be about 0.25 the mass of Earth.  Using a mass of 0.5 Earth mass, which should plenty massive enough, at a semi-major axis of 428,952 km a moon would have a Hill radius of 15,253.202 km.  12 times that would be 183,038.424 km, and there would be room for 14.724 moons in an orbit with a circumference of 2,695,182.627 km.
If there are 14 equally spaced moons in orbit with a circumference of 2,695,182.627 km they would be spaced 192,513 kilometers apart.  One early design for a space elevator envisioned it extending far beyond geostationary orbit at 35,785 km to a height of 144,000 km.  So a space elevator between two co-orbital moons might be only 1.3369 times a long as that design.
Possibly more recent designs could be shorter, but 35,785 km seems to be minimum possible length and 192,513 km is only about 5.379 times that length.
Thus a space elevator like structure between two moons sharing a common orbit around a giant planet seems to be approximately as plausible as a space elevator.
